# How can I use syntax match with literal `*` correctly?

Tags: vim

Consider the following vim syntax rules, which I am using to change the color of words surrounded by `*`.

```
syntax match boldme /\*.\{-1,}\*/
highlight boldme ctermfg=Red
```

For some reason, this rule only works if the word is at the beginning of a line, `*hello*` is red in the first line below but not the second line.

```
*hello* works
Another word and *hello* does not work.
```

How can I make `syn match` work in the middle of a line for the scenario above?

---

**Update**: This problem appears to be specific to using the literal `*` character as part of the match. The following match works fine for using `_` instead.

```
syntax match boldme /_.\+_/
```

Thus the question is really, *how do I force vim to treat a literal `*` character correctly in `syn match`*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
syntax match boldme /\*.\+\*/
```

#### Update

I don't know how did you do the test, see this gif animation with `vim -u NONE`:

[image]

Comment: I had already tried that and just tried again. Exactly same effect. Were you able to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot. I just observed that adding `set ft=` makes it works, but I am trying to make it work as part of a syntax file. I will update my question in a bit with more repro details.

Comment: When I tried to isolate the problem, I could not reproduce it, so I accept this answer. My problem lies elsewhere, in the interaction between syntax rules.

Comment: Root cause was that I had this line earlier in the syntax file.  `syntax match badMatch /^.*/`. Unclear why it did not effect the other syntax rules.

Comment: When two matches occur at the same location, the last-defined rule will win. Thus boldme can work at the beginning of the line, overriding badmatch. But since boldme does not have a containedin=badmatch, and badmatch does not have a contains=boldme, boldme cannot match within badmatch.